# Angular NgModel not assigning select value to object parameter

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ng-modules

Im trying to assing the value of a select option to the name of an object in Angular. The list of names is showing correctly, but upon submitting the form the value is empty. I did import the FormsModule in app.module.ts like other posts on here say, but that's not the problem I guess.

Anyone able to pass along some wisdom?

```
<Select [(ngModel)]="object.name" name="name" class="u-border-1 u-border-grey-30 u-input u-input-rectangle u-white" required>
                        <option value="" disabled>Kies naam</option>
                        <option [value]="'Andreas'">Andreas</option>
                        <option [value]="'Lucas'">Lucas</option>
                        <option [value]="'Samen'">Samen</option>
                    </Select>
```

Comment: It may be because the html tag is `select` with lowercase **s**. And please avoid the use of images to include code in your questions and include it as text.

Comment: That was it, thanks man. And I'll keep that in mind next time!

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in comment by akotech:

> It may be because the HTML tag is `select` with lowercase `s`.